# Rabbitmq not leaving startup on solaris 10

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I am trying to get Rabbitmq to work on solaris 10 (sparc). when I run Rabbitmq I get ot the start up screen

```
          RabbitMQ 3.6.1. Copyright (C) 2007-2016 Pivotal Software, Inc.
##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
##  ##
##########  Logs: /opt/rabbitmq/log/rabbit@192.168.0.1.log
######  ##        /opt/rabbitmq/log/rabbit@192.168.0.1-sasl.log
##########
          Starting broker... completed with 8 plugins.
```

and then it just hangs at this point if I do rabbitmqctl status

```
Status of node 'rabbit@192.168.0.1' ...
Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@192.168.0.1': nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@192.168.0.1']

rabbit@192.168.0.1:
   * connected to epmd (port 4369) on 192.168.0.1
   * epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672
   * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
   * suggestion: hostname mismatch?
   * suggestion: is the cookie set correctly?
   * suggestion: is the Erlang distribution using TLS?
```

I've checked through everything and I can't find anything wrong with any of the suggestions.

here is my config file

```
[
    {rabbit, [
                {tcp_listeners, [4003]},
                {loopback_users, []},
                {cluster_nodes, {['rabbit@192.168.0.1'], disc}}
    ]},
    {rabbitmq_management, [{listener, [{port, 15672}]}]}
].
```

I've tried do this with and without ssl configuration same problem.
my Erlang version is 18.3 and rabbitmq is 3.6.1
what am I missing here that's causing it to hang up after it says completed?

edit here is my ps aux output and rabbitmq logs

```
    =INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:15:49 ===
Starting RabbitMQ 3.6.1 on Erlang 18.3
Copyright (C) 2007-2016 Pivotal Software, Inc.
Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:15:50 ===
node           : rabbit@192.168.0.1
home dir       : /export/home/jckunz
config file(s) : /opt/rabbitmq/config/rabbitmq.config
cookie hash    : eF4lT09DIn3wKUXARVnbrw==
log            : /opt/rabbitmq/log/rabbit@192.168.0.1.log
sasl log       : /opt/rabbitmq/log/rabbit@192.168.0.1-sasl.log
database dir   : /opt/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@192.168.0.1

=WARNING REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:04 ===
You are using a 32-bit version of Erlang: you may run into memory address
space exhaustion or statistic counters overflow.

=WARNING REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:04 ===
Only 2048MB of 32640MB memory usable due to limited address space.
Crashes due to memory exhaustion are possible - see
http://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html#address-space

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:04 ===
Memory limit set to 819MB of 32640MB total.

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:04 ===
Disk free limit set to 50MB

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:04 ===
Limiting to approx 156 file handles (138 sockets)

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:04 ===
FHC read buffering:  OFF
FHC write buffering: ON

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:04 ===
Database directory at /opt/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@192.168.0.1 is empty. Initialising from scratch...

=WARNING REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:04 ===
Could not find any node for auto-clustering from: ['rabbit@192.168.0.1']
Starting blank node...

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:05 ===
Priority queues enabled, real BQ is rabbit_variable_queue

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:05 ===
Management plugin: using rates mode 'basic'

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:05 ===
msg_store_transient: using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:05 ===
msg_store_persistent: using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index

=WARNING REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:05 ===
msg_store_persistent: rebuilding indices from scratch

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:05 ===
Adding vhost '/'

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:05 ===
Creating user 'guest'

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:05 ===
Setting user tags for user 'guest' to [administrator]

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:05 ===
Setting permissions for 'guest' in '/' to '.*', '.*', '.*'

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:05 ===
started TCP Listener on [::]:4003

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:05 ===
started TCP Listener on 0.0.0.0:4003

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:05 ===
Management plugin started. Port: 15672

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:05 ===
Statistics database started.

=INFO REPORT==== 4-May-2016::10:16:05 ===
Server startup complete; 8 plugins started.
 * rabbitmq_federation_management
 * rabbitmq_management
 * rabbitmq_management_agent
 * rabbitmq_federation
 * amqp_client
 * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
 * webmachine
 * mochiweb


USER       PID %CPU %MEM   SZ  RSS TT       S    START  TIME COMMAND
jckunz  19849  1.1  0.4327960118576 pts/1    S 10:15:44 10:32 /opt/rabbitmq/solaris/erlang/erts-7.3/bin/beam.smp -W w -A 64 -P 1048576 
-B i -- -root /opt/rabbitmq/solaris/erlang -progname erl -- -home /export/home/jckunz -epmd_port 4369 -- -pa /opt/rabbitmq/solaris/rabbitmq/ebin 
-noshell -noinput -s rabbit boot -name rabbit@192.168.0.1 -boot start_sasl -config /opt/rabbitmq/config/rabbitmq 
-kernel inet_default_connect_options [{nodelay,true}] -sasl errlog_type error -sasl sasl_error_logger false 
-rabbit error_logger {file,"/opt/rabbitmq/log/rabbit@192.168.0.1.log"} -rabbit sasl_error_logger {file,"/opt/rabbitmq/log/rabbit@192.168.0.1-sasl.log"} 
-rabbit enabled_plugins_file "/opt/rabbitmq/config/enabled_plugins" -rabbit plugins_dir "/opt/rabbitmq/solaris/rabbitmq/plugins" 
-rabbit plugins_expand_dir "/opt/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@192.168.0.1-plugins-expand" -os_mon start_cpu_sup false -os_mon start_disksup false -os_mon start_memsup false 
-mnesia dir "/opt/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@192.168.0.1" -setcookie jckunz -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 25672 
-kernel inet_dist_listen_max 25672 inet_dist_listen_max 25672

jckunz  19711  0.1  0.329051277936 pts/1    S 10:15:42  0:50 /opt/rabbitmq/solaris/erlang/erts-7.3/bin/beam.smp -- -root /opt/rabbitmq/solaris/erlang 
-progname erl -- -home /export/home/jckunz -epmd_port 4369 -- -pa /opt/rabbitmq/solaris/rabbitmq/ebin -noshell -noinput -hidden -setcookie jckunz 
-boot start_clean -sasl errlog_type error -mnesia dir "/opt/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@192.168.0.1" -s rabbit_control_main -nodename rabbit@192.168.0.1 
-extra wait /opt/rabbitmq/solaris/rabbitmq/sbin/lock
```

Comment: You will need to access the shell on the started node or view its logs to debug the problem. At this moment your node is starting (epmd shows it's running) but an application hangs preventing other applications from starting and the node from fully being booted. In my system this could be caused for example by incorrect name of the mnesia database. If you do `ps aux` (or equivalent on your system) you should be able see how the rabbit node was started. Also look in starting scripts. You want to know where is the path to logs or to the shell file. You connect to the shell with `to_erl` command.

Comment: @Amiramix the `to_erl` command says it can't find erlang.pipe. Ive added an edit my post showing my rabbitmq logs and aux command if there are other erlang logs i can't find them.

Comment: The option `-noshell` means that the node is started with no shell access. You can try to copy the whole command from the ps output and start the node manually omitting the `-noshell` argument (and of course ensuring that the original node is stopped). You can also try to inspect the logs that the node should be writing while starting - the exact file names are in that long command. BTW why in your output the node is started twice, once with pid 19849 and once with 19711? They both try to access the same mnesia db, is that correct?

Comment: @Amiramix i've posted rabbit@192.168.0.1.log and rabbit@192.168.0.1-sasl.log just gives me `ancestors: [<0.156.0>] messages: [{'EXIT',<0.158.0>,normal}] links: [<0.156.0>,<0.7.0>]dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 1598
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 203
  neighbours:
`

Comment: Looks like a process is receiving an EXIT signal from another process. You will need to capture logs from the process that is exiting. It's PID seemed to be <0.158.0> at that time. You could grep logs for that PID in the hope that the process was logged. On the other hand the exit type is `normal` so there may be nothing wrong with the process. Did you try to start the node with the shell access?

Comment: @Amiramix after removing the the -noshell and -noinput options I a shell starts up with rabbitmq the logo and starting broker completed with 8 plugins appears and I can enter in commands. what should I enter?

Comment: `application:which_applications().`. This will list all running applications. You can then compare to the list of applications that should have been started. Then `node().`, `nodes().` and `erlang:get_cookie().` to see node names and cookies. Then maybe `release_handler:which_releases().` to see the current release. Then you can try to ping one node from the other to see what error you get, see http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html for details.